# How to remove all instances of a string from output in linux terminal commands

Tags: linux

This command almost does everything I am needing

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -f6- -d : | sort | uniq
```

but I can't figure out how to sort out a specific string

I need to remove "/remove/this" from any line where it occurs and I need the lines of text not to be broken up for 1 word per line.

The purpose of the command is List all of the shells used by at least one user on the system, without duplicates.

Wold appreciate any input.

Comment: Did you consider sed?

Comment: I tried using sed -i -e 's/\</remove/this//g' but I can't get it to work. Unknown options to 's'

Comment: something like this is what you want though, do some experiments with simpler patterns. Escape `/` with `\\` or just use another character (any one will do which does not appear in passwd).

Comment: And I suggest you change your question to "why does this sed pattern not work?", because it should and will work when done properly. That way you get better reponses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed`. When the pattern you are looking for contains `/`, you should use a different separator character. I find `:` quite readable.

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -f6- -d : | sort | uniq | sed s:/remove/this::
```

Since sed will change some lines, it's better to move sort + uniq to the end of the pipeline. `sort -u` combines both programs.

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -f6- -d : | sed s:/remove/this:: | sort -u
```

Comment: This still leaves /remove/this in every line.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misspelled anything in the pattern?

Comment: I am sure, I have  cat /etc/passwd | cut -f6- -d : sort | uniq | sed s:/remove/this:: but /remove/this is still in the same lines of output.

Comment: Ah, my mistake., I spelled it wrong. It works. Sorry about that.

Comment: With regular expression you will not get an error message when you've done a typo. So it's not uncommon for minor typos to sneak in. When you don't know why your expression isn't working, just start with a very short expression like `s:/::` and test that it works. Then you can add more complexity step by step, until you have something that gives you the exact result you want.

Comment: It does not make sense to put the `sed` command after the `uniq`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single awk command for that:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/\/remove\/this/, "", $NF);a[$NF]} END{for(i in a){print i}}' /etc/passwd
```

`-F:` splits the line by `:`.

The first block runs on every line of input while `sub(/\/remove\/this/, "", $NF)` removes the string from the last column and `a[$NF]` creates and index for every shell found in passwd. Obviously if the index already exists, it will not get created again. Doing so we dedup the data.

At the `END` of input we are iterating trough the array `a` and print every index: `{for(i in a){print i}}`